# Graphics Driver Installation

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

I am using Acer Predator helios 300 which comes with integrated intel graphics card and nvidia 1050ti graphics .
Using Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS kernal version `Linux 5.0.0-31-generic` But when I do `lshw -c display` .

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4080000-a40fffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

I tried to install nvidia graphics driver but getting error

```
compilation terminated.
scripts/Makefile.build:284: recipe for target '/tmp/selfgz7993/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.20/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-fence.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/selfgz7993/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.20/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-fence.o] Error 1
make[2]: Target '__build' not remade because of errors.
Makefile:1608: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/selfgz7993/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.20/kernel' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/selfgz7993/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.20/kernel] Error 2
make[1]: Target 'modules' not remade because of errors.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-31-generic'
Makefile:81: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
ERROR: The nvidia kernel module was not created.
```

Comment: You haven't said what release.  The first paste should have been run with `sudo` elevating privileges (thus warning message you also pasted), and I get the feeling you've edited the nvidia compile missing key messages, or missed it when pasting.  Did you try and install binary drivers?  (ie. using `ubuntu-drivers`)

Comment: It's Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS kernal version `Linux 5.0.0-31-generic` . I also tried to install binary drivers using `ubuntu-drivers` but while doing it was getting `connection refused many times`